# How can I open a complex URL in Safari from command line

Tags: macos, command-line, safari, kibana

With `curl -s -n -k 'https://icinga.mycompany.com:5665/v1/objects/services/mls!elasticsearch-query-nginx-error-log' | jq -r '.results[0].attrs.notes_url'` I got these URL from our icinga2 API:

`https://logs.mycompany.com/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,value:0),time:(from:now-30d,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(columns:!(level,severity,message),index:'production.production-mls',interval:auto,query:(language:lucene,query:'application:"mls" AND (facility:"mls.nginx.error" OR (facility:"mls.nginx.access" AND NOT http.response_code:[200 TO 399])) AND @timestamp:>now-15m AND NOT url_path:/\/test.*/'),sort:!('@timestamp',desc))`

How can I open it from the command line?

I already tried

```
URL=$(curl -s -n -k 'https://icinga.mycompany.com:5665/v1/objects/services/mls!elasticsearch-query-nginx-error-log' | jq -r '.results[0].attrs.notes_url')
open -a safari "$URL"
```

With `open` the string gets URL encoded and no longer works because of the encoded `#` after `kibana`.

I need a solution that also works with other complex URLs.

Comment: That is not a URL, thats some sort of server log with snippets of database query and variables interspersed.